# Delphi - TCameraComponent auto focus

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to use auto focus in TCameraComponent with this code :

```
CameraComponent.FocusMode := TFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus;
```

but I get the following error :  delphi java.lang.runtimeexception: setparameters failed.
How can I use autofocus. I'm in Delphi XE10 Seattle.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you obtain this error?  On execution? On Compile?

Answer (score 0):

Because FMX not fully implemented autofocus function on Android.

Answer (score -1):

It's not FMX that's the issue. It's the capability of the device.

I have used the above code successfully on a samsung galaxy tab running android 7. I have also had the above error when running on an older device.